# Set column value in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array, that has two values, an ID value, and a price value, as such:

***cartarray***
**ID**  - **Price**
23 - 0.10
24 - 10.00

Using the ID's, an SQL query selects rows of data from the database as such:

```
SELECT * FROM video A 
JOIN artists B 
    ON(A.UPLOADERID=B.ARTISTID) 
WHERE ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($cartarray[0]['ID'])."' 
    OR ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($cartarray[1]['ID'])."' 
ORDER BY ID
```

the problem is that the prices are no longer affiliated with the row in the newly acquired data, how would i code this to have a new column in the retrieved data, that is the appropriate price?

Comment: I will bet that this is not the _original_ query you are using .. when saying you acquired data from it

Comment: No, its not, my original query is dynamically generated depending on an input array, its a static example of it.